# PHPUnit test failing on plugin

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, phpunit, bootstrapping

my phpunit test fails with this error:

```
C:\workspace\internal_jets3\tests>phpunit --verbose
PHPUnit 3.5.7 by Sebastian Bergmann.


Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on a non-object in C:\worksp
ace\internal_jets3\library\My\Controller\Plugin\ModuleLayoutLoader.php on line 7
```

Extract from plugin:

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_ModuleLayoutLoader extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $config = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getOptions();
```

Any help on how to include plugins in testing will be helpful. Thanks!

Edit @Gordon
It's not really that obvious to me.
Doing a var_dump of:

```
var_dump(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap'));
die();
```

gives me:

```
object(Bootstrap)[3]
      protected '_appNamespace' => boolean false
      protected '_resourceLoader' => null
      protected '_application' =>
```

which says 'object' to me; and halfway down the dump is:

```
  protected '_options' =>
```

So this confuses me - I'm not familiar how to correctly phpunit test this object.

Comment: And that's why static methods, singletons, and chaining (in order) are so hard to test and kill maintainability...

Comment: Well, the error message is obvious, isnt it? You are trying to call a method on something that isn't an object. Make sure `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')` actually does what you think it does.

Comment: When did you do the var_dump ? During the tests from phpunit or during the normal execution of your application?

Comment: @Marcin, I did it before the static method line. I have however removed this plugin, and I'm currently just changing the module in via action helpers in the init of my controllers, since I only need it for now on 1 module.

Answer (score 1):

to set up PHPUnit in Zend environment, you have to fire your Zend bootstrap inside your phpunit bootstrap. After this, you still have a bootstrap object in your application. 
And your errormessage said that `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')`
is NULL. Are you sure, that you've debugged at the right place?

Comment: No, it's not null, it's a huge dump. That extract is to show it's an object. But alas, I'll have to do some research on how to test (or not use) static methods. I'm am running a testsuite via phpunit.xml and it's bootstrapped fine.